# How to force a type to be a subclass of another type in C#

Tags: c#

Does anyone knows how to make sure a Type's value inherits from the Type of a superclass?

```
public class MyClass {

    private Type myType;  // where the type is a subclass MySuperClass type

}
```

I know how to do it in Java with:

```
private Class<? extends MySuperClass> clazz;
```

But I wonder how to do it in C#

Comment: [Could you explain why you want to do this?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I want to create new instances from the type with Activator.CreateInstance later

Comment: Do you need run time or compile time check ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use where:

```
class Myclass<Type> where Type: Superclass
```

Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-generic-type-constraint

Answer (score 0):

To reply to Skaparate, this is not exactly what I want. I dont want to be forced to create a new class anytime i want to use Types as attribute (example for lists of types)

So I a created a class similar to java.lang.Class and I'll add methods anytime i need:

```
public class Class<T> where T : class {
    public T newInstance()
    {
        return (T) Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
    }

    public T newInstance(params object[] parameters)
    {
        return (T) Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), parameters);
    }

    public new Type GetType()
    {
        return typeof(T);
    }
}

public abstract class Spell {

    // as a battle animation's attributes changes during the animation I want to recreate a new one anytime this spell is used
    private Class<BattleAnimation> animation;

    public BattleAnimation GetAnimation() {
        return this.animation.newInstance();
    }

}
```